# AngularJS: Dynamic locale

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, locale, angular-translate

I'm using [**Angular Dynamic locale**](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) and [**Angular-Translate**](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) for internationalization and localization (*i18n*). And works well.

I like the idea of **angular-translate** that is possible to change the language without refresh the page.

- *Is possible to do the same with **Angular Dynamic locale**? If is possible, how can I get this?*

All the words from angular-translate changed automatically, but not the words from angular_locale (*datapicker, etc*), that the users need refreshing the page.

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just in case you don't have absolute necessity to use Angular Dynamic locale,you can create your own LocaleFactory like this:

```
 factory('LocaleFactory', function ( $locale, $translate) {
    var locales = {
        nl: {
            "DATETIME_FORMATS": {
                "AMPMS"     : [
                    "AM",
                    "PM"
                ],
                "DAY"       : [
                    "zondag",
                    "maandag",
                    "dinsdag",
                    "woensdag",
                    "donderdag",
                    "vrijdag",
                    "zaterdag"
                ],
                "MONTH"     : [
                    "januari",
                    "februari",
                    "maart",
                    "april",
                    "mei",
                    "juni",
                    "juli",
                    "augustus",
                    "september",
                    "oktober",
                    "november",
                    "december"
                ],
                "SHORTDAY"  : [
                    "zo",
                    "ma",
                    "di",
                    "wo",
                    "do",
                    "vr",
                    "za"
                ],
                "SHORTMONTH": [
                    "jan.",
                    "feb.",
                    "mrt.",
                    "apr.",
                    "mei",
                    "jun.",
                    "jul.",
                    "aug.",
                    "sep.",
                    "okt.",
                    "nov.",
                    "dec."
                ],

                "fullDate"  : "EEEE d MMMM y",
                "longDate"  : "d MMMM y",
                "medium"    : "d MMM y HH:mm:ss",
                "mediumDate": "d MMM y",
                "mediumTime": "HH:mm:ss",
                "short"     : "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm",
                "shortDate" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
                "shortTime" : "HH:mm"
            },
            "NUMBER_FORMATS"  : {
                "CURRENCY_SYM": "\u20ac",
                "DECIMAL_SEP" : ",",
                "GROUP_SEP"   : ".",
                "PATTERNS"    : [
                    {
                        "gSize"  : 3,
                        "lgSize" : 3,
                        "macFrac": 0,
                        "maxFrac": 3,
                        "minFrac": 0,
                        "minInt" : 1,
                        "negPre" : "-",
                        "negSuf" : "",
                        "posPre" : "",
                        "posSuf" : ""
                    },
                    {
                        "gSize"  : 3,
                        "lgSize" : 3,
                        "macFrac": 0,
                        "maxFrac": 2,
                        "minFrac": 2,
                        "minInt" : 1,
                        "negPre" : "\u00a4\u00a0",
                        "negSuf" : "-",
                        "posPre" : "\u00a4\u00a0",
                        "posSuf" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        setLocale: function (key) {
            $translate.use(key);
            angular.copy(locales[key], $locale);
        }
    };
});
```

Similarly you can add other locals as well

Call setLocale to change the locale

```
run(function (LocaleFactory) {
    LocaleFactory.setLocale('nl');
});
```

When ever your locale get changed you can call setLocale by providing the locale key as  an argument. It will change your locale instantly

Comment: Works!!!!! Thank you very much!!!!!! :) And another question hehe... You know if is possible to do the same with `am-time-ago` from `angular-moment`? For the moment I'm using `amMoment.changeLocale('de');`, but the users need refreshing the page again for translations! hehe! Thank you!

Comment: Uo! Just the same solution works for Angular-moment! Is using the same locale? Nice! Thank you !! haha